What it meant by "secondary odometry" in the robot localization for parameter odom0_pose_use_child_frame
In the documentation for robot localization, a parameter called "odom0_pose_use_child_frame" is used to transform the incoming odom message from its child frame into the robot base frame specified by robot localization (given that the two frames has a non-zero offset) (at least this is how I interpret it.) However, it specifically says
"# Set to true for fusing secondary odometry sources that are rigidly connected to base_link but has a non-zero
# offset from base_link. "
What is meant by secondary odometry, as opposed to primary? And why should this matter if it is applied to secondary or primary? I would assume the distinction would be GNSS odometry vs wheel odometry, but I do not see how it matters what type of odometry comes into the filter, as long as there is a connection between the frame specified by the odom message and the robot base frame specified by robot localization, the filter should transform the incoming message into the robot base frame regardless (given that it is not already receiving data from the robot base frame)


odom0_pose_use_child_frame is used to transform the incoming odom message from its child frame into the robot base frame specified by robot localization

No, that's not the reason for the parameter. That's the default behaviour for robot_localization. If a message contains pose data, then we try to transform it from the message's frame_id field into the state estimation node's world_frame. If it contains velocity data, then we try to transform that velocity data from the message's child_frame_id into the state estimation node's base_link_frame.
To understand that parameter, see this issue and PR:
https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/726
https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/pull/728
The idea is that if that parameter is true for a given sensor, then we apply the base_link_frame->child_frame_id transform to the pose data before fusing it.
